# Trying to reconstruct the reasoning leading to the intentionality of consciousness ( Husserl's phenomenology)

Tags: consciousness, phenomenology, husserl, intentionality

I would like to have feedbacks on the following way to reconstruct Husserl's reasong in Cartesian Meditations as to the relationship of consciousness to its objects, and more generally to the world.

(1) If the relation A has to B is only an external ( accidental) relation, then, in case B ceases to exist, then A is no longer related to B.

(2) Therefore, if the relation of consciousness to the world is only an external relation, then, in case the world did not exist, consciousness would no longer be related to the world.

(3) Now, let us place ourselves in a situation in which the world were only a coherent dream; let us bracket our beleif in the existence of the world; so to say, let us place ourselves in the situation in which the world has ceased to exist.

(4) In this situation, the relation of consciousness to the world remains what it was : the world is still " there" , present to consciousness, at least as a phenomenon.

(5) Therefore, the relation of consciousness to the world is not an external one, but an internal one: consciousness bears in itself this relation; any " cogitatio" ( act of thought) bears in itself a relation to its " cogitatum" ( object of thought).

The problem I see in this reconstruction ( and in Husserl's reasoning as I understand it so far) is a possible confusion between (a) knowing what happens when I imagine the world does not exist and (b) knowing what would really follow in case this situation actually occurred.

To what extent this " thought-experiment" of a world that vanishes allows us to tell whether consciousness would still be in relation with a phenomenal world in case the physical universe ( to which we ascribe existence in the " natural attitude") actually did not exist?

What are the hidden premises or presuppositions in Husserl's reasoning?

Note. The form of the reasoning would be

(1) IF A THEN ( IF not-B THEN not-C)

(2) Not-B does not imply not-C

(3) Not-A.